# Integrate Wordpress post/blog in my website

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, integrate

I have a [site](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/) which is the cms of Eccube ( ecommerce) . It doesnt have dynamic post feature like in wordpress and all.
I want to integrate the wordpress inside my website. It can be anywhere like new page or anywhere. 
I have also installed wordpress inside eccube directory with folder name BLOG . 
So the actual path is like this :-
/public_html/azlily.awe.jp/eccube_1/html/blog
I have created a new post, thats fine but going to that post will open in wordpress templates, It will look like two different websites. I want the post to appear inside my eccube website but not with wordpress website.

Any solution for this. I googled but only found Wordpress and html website hook up but not with eccube.

Answer (score 0):

Only one option is redirect wordpress blog to "www.example.com/blog" or "blog.example.com" on click

You can access wordpress blog from "BLOG" folder directly

You need to change layout of the wordpress blog so that it will match with your main website, So that it wont appear like two different websites

Comment: How can i change the layout of the website to match with my website?

Comment: you need to change css and all for wordpress files